# Is it possible to stack values from 4 different columns from two different sheets into one column in third sheet using formula?

Tags: excel

I need a formula that takes all the non-blank values from columns N and O in sheet1,
columns E and F in sheet2
and put them all in one column B in sheet3

Comment: `=VSTACK(TOCOL(Sheet1!N:O,1),TOCOL(Sheet2!E:F,1))`

Comment: it's giving me an #NAME1 error @JvdV